# htmlpurifier not working when doing post input form

Tags: php, codeigniter, htmlpurifier

I am using htmlpurifier in codeigniter application. when i am using the html directly its filtering. For example:

```
    $dirty_html = 'T<svg onload=alert(1);>est';
    $clean_html = purify($dirty_html);
    echo $clean_html;
```

I am getting the filtered output when i use it plain but when i am using with POST its not filtering. Please check the example below.

```
    Output: test
```

when i am using post ie., $this->input->post('name'); not filtering at all.

```
    $dirty_html = $this->input->post('name');
    $clean_html = purify($dirty_html);
    echo $clean_html;

    Output: t<svg onload=alert(1);>est
```

getting the above output when using post. Its not filtering.

Comment: what is in `purify()`

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/htmlpurifier

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use input->post() it already return a value which filtered by htmlspecialchars() so the purifier will not be applied

Comment: i need to filter the post input from form? how to do that ??